# How do I port this line from Python 2 to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, typechecking

This is the line:

```
if type(tup) is types.TupleType:
```

Seriously, I'm lost. I tried Google without success. This is the error I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'TupleType'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if type(tup) is tuple:
```

will work on both 2.7 and 3.x. `types.TupleType` was already an alias of the built-in `tuple` type in 2.x (`tuple is types.TupleType` returns `True`).

If you want to be more flexible and allow `tuple` subclasses, I'd suggest:

```
if isinstance(tup, tuple):
```

but that could conceivably change behavior (e.g. allowing `namedtuple`s to pass the test, not just raw base class `tuple`s).